# Any experience with PHP obfuscator on pipsomania.com

Tags: php, obfuscation

I'm looking for any php obfuscator solution, I found one
http://www.pipsomania.com/best_php_obfuscator.do
but I need to send our code to their service.

Have you anyone any experience with this service? I'm little bit worried :-)

PS. Our goal is to protect a code from easy observation and we don't want to install any php extension on every server where we sold our product. So I thing products like Zend Guard are out of the game.

Thanks a lot,
Jaro.

Comment: Why do you think this is the best PHP obfuscator you can get? Their site says it doesn't work for some PHP constructs (from the site: " Known issues: Currently does not support the backtick operator If your code contains such, it will probably result in wrong obfuscated code which is giving you errors. ...")

Answer (score 2):

I have not used their desktop version, but I have tried the online free version.

It's clever, and the author is right to say it has maximum compatibility. But a few hours later and I have a program that reverses the obfuscation.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the desktop version but I also have worries that it can be completely broken or not. When I tried I decoded about 20 - 25% of the code. But if there is a decoder software, I'll be happy if you can share. I need to test before trust and rely on it.

Comment: I wrote a decoder because some of our code was obfuscated but out of respect for the pipsomania author I will not share that code. If you wish, you can send me your code and I'll try to unobfuscated it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice software but need jar

https://gist.github.com/1171816

java -jar Coolphpobfuscator.jar phpfilename.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the desktop version. For me the advantage is compatibility. I have a problematic file which didn't worked with any encoder or obfuscator except (useless) base64 encoding and pipsomania. Since I saw it I started to use.